# How to create a query nodes, that queries content with more than one comment?

Tags: 8, database, comments

Consider this example:

```
  $query = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->getQuery();
  $nids = $query->condition('type', 'question')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->condition('field_category', $tid)
    ->sort('created', 'DESC')
    ->pager(10)
    ->execute();
  $questions = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($nids);
```

I would like to only query the questions, with answers. (that are comments)
I was hoping adding `->condition('comment_node_question.0.comment_count', '0', '>')` would work, but no luck.